# rabbitmq-plugin returns "error could not recognize command"

Tags: rabbitmq, windows-server-2012

I installed rabbitmq for windows server 2012. it installed properly.I want to run rabbitmq_management command inside the rabbitmq-plugin.bat but the bat file when double clicked throughs "error could not recognize command".Googled the error didn't find a thing.How can i ovveride the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open a `cmd` terminal, go to the rabbitmq `sbin` folder and execute:

`rabbitmq-plugin.bat enable rabbitmq_management`